# Decimal separator in NumberFormat

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting

Given a locale java.text.NumberFormat:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

How can I get the character used as Decimal separator (if it's a comma or a point) in that numberformat? How can I modify this property without having to use new DecimalFormat(format)?

Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The helper class [DecimalFomatSymbols](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) is what you are looking for:

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char sep=symbols.getDecimalSeparator();
```

To set you symbols as needed:

```
//create a new instance
DecimalFormatSymbols custom=new DecimalFormatSymbols();
custom.setDecimalSeparator(',');
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(custom);
```

**EDIT:** this answer is only valid for `DecimalFormat`, and not for `NumberFormat` as required in the question. Anyway, as it may help the author, I'll let it here.

Comment: For the record, Numberformat is an abstract class, so you'll probably actually have a DecimalFormat object anyway.

Comment: @locster: either a `DecimalFormat` or a `ChoiceFormat` or an undocumented JDK-private `NumberFormat` implementation or ...

Comment: For the record, this line
_DecimalFormat format=DecimalFormat.getInstance();_
doesn't compile as the getInstance() method returns a NumberFormat object.

Comment: or to be even safer; `new DecimalFormat().getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()`

Comment: or take remove the dependency entirely: `new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)).getDecimalSeparator()`

Comment: As recommended in the [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), you should test the instance of your NumberFormat instance: `if (nf instanceof DecimalFormat) { ... }`

Answer (score 6):

I agree with *biziclop* and *Joachim Sauer* that messing with decimal and grouping separators and doing this work manually, can cause a lot of problems. Use of the locale parameter in the `NumberFormat` getInstance method does all the work for you automatically. And you can easily disable the thousand grouping separator, if you wish so.

The following junit test method (which passes) shows this behavior based on English and German locale.

```
public void testFormatter() {
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
    assertEquals('.', formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()); //true

    formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    assertEquals(',', formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()); //true

    //and in case you want another decimal seperator for a specific locale
    DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');

    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
    assertEquals('.', formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()); //true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If** your [`NumberFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instance is a [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), then you can use [`getDecimalFormatSymbols()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#getDecimalFormatSymbols%28%29) to get to that information.

In general, you can't get to that information.

Why do you need it?

Comment: I want to make possible to the user to use either comma or point as decimal separator, so I need to replace commas with points or points with commas depending on the locale used.

Comment: Good point. I overlooked that he was using NumberFormat and not DecimalFormat.

Comment: You can set the default DecimalFormatSymbols for the Locale.

Comment: This is a potentially dangerous idea, as some locales use dots for group separators and commas for decimal separator (e.g. "123.456,78"), switching them around might cause considerable confusion.

Comment: @Javi: if that's what you want to do, then why don't you simply request the *correct `NumberFormat` for the users locale* in the first place? Messing with the `NumberFormat` for one locale to tweak *some* of its parameters to fit another locale sounds like a formidable recipe for disaster!

Comment: Note to self: read comments before commenting ;-) @bizclop provided an excellent example for what I meant to say.

Comment: I'll take it into account. In my case it is not going to happen because numbers are percentages always under 100, so there is not going to be a group separator. But I do agree that it it may be confusing.

Comment: @Javi: are you sure that there are no locales that use grouping separators with 2 digits? Or that use a different minus sign? Or something else? **If** you know the whole set of possible formats, hardcode them in your application and don't use the `getInstance()` ones. Otherwise, use the `getInstance()` ones, but use them correctly.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I was going to disable grouping separators. Anyway it was an just an idea because Spanish Locale use comma as decimal separator, though numeric keyboards have a point so if the user uses the numeric keybord when he presses the decimal separator it may be confusing. I was just to help the user because numbers were not going to be so big. If it has problems I'll take this away.