# How can I make input fields accept locale dependent number formatting?

Tags: spring-mvc, localization, jstl

I'm working on a Spring MVC Project and ran into a problem with the internationalization in forms, especially the number formatting.

I already use fmt:formatNumber to format the numbers according to the current selected locale.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${object[field]}"/>
```

Like this, number formatting works well when I display numbers. But how about the forms?

At the moment, the input fields that are supposed to receive float values are prefilled with 0.0 and expect me to use "." as decimal separator, no matter what locale is selected. Values containing "," are refused by the server (...can not convert String to required type float...).

How can I make my input fields use and accept the appropriate number format as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at [`@NumberFormat`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html)? If you annotate the property the input field is bound to, this should result in the proper formatting. Something like:

```
@NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
private BigDecimal something;
```

This style is the ["general-purpose number format for the current locale"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.Style.html#NUMBER). I guess, the current locale is determined threadwise from the [`LocaleContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html).

Your app needs to be [annotation-driven](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/), also see the section ["Annotation-driven Formatting"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-CustomFormatAnnotations) in the docs.

You might want to take a look at the [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4713217/95033).

Comment: But how does your solution work, if I need to switch between multiple locales? My problem is, that I don't have just one pattern, but the pattern can be "#,###.###" or "#.###,###" depending on locale.

Comment: Edited my answer (added some more links and removed the pattern, which was a bad example). I guess you should read all the docs on that annotations and classes and play around if it works in your application with different locales. See if the formatting is as you intended.