# Put commas in a number string?

Tags: gwt

Given a number, I'd like to transform it into a string, but insert commas in the thousands place etc, like:

```
int number = 123456;
String formatted = String.valueOf(number);
println(formatted); // but print "123,456"?
```

does GWT offer a way of doing this, or should we write our own method?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449805/how-to-format-a-number-from-1123456789-to-1-123-456-789-in-c/1449859#1449859 for a C version which should be easy enough to port to Java.

Comment: See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is to format a number with decimal points and include a comma. The other is with out decimal points. I'm giving this out because it wasn't so easy for me to figure it out the first time when I was starting out.

```
private NumberFormat decFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)");
private NumberFormat intFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,##0;(#,##0)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [NumberFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html) provided by GWT.