# Best way to convert string to double

Tags: java, double

i need to convert some strings to double.

These strings comes from third part services and possibly changes format.

I need to create a function that takes a string and returns a double.

The strings could be:

1. "80.00"
2. "80.50"
3. "80,50"
4. "80,00"
5. "80"
6. "1.500.50"
7. "1500.50"
8. "1500,00"
   Etc...

What i try is:

```
function double convert(String s){
    s = s.replace(".","").replace(",",".");
    return Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

This doesn't cover all the situation.

Can please someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: that's too painful. how could you know `1,500` is `1.500` or `1500`?

Comment: Isn't your replace going to turn 80.00 into 8000, 1.500.00 into 150000 etc?

Comment: How does one convert #6 to a double?

Comment: Agree with @HuStmpHrrr. Need more information about the locale first.

Comment: Is the decimal place guaranteed to be 2 characters? If not, 180,000 can be interpreted both as 180K or 180 depending on locale.

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the following approach? It replaces all `,` by `.` and removes all but the last `.`:

```
public double convert(String s){
    s = s.replace(",",".").replaceAll("\\.(?=.*\\.)","");
    return Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: Well `1,000,000` looks like one million to me.

Comment: @aioobe: Sure, but it isn't possible to cover all possible number formats. This covers all of OPs examples at least.

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks! it covers all the format. Thanks Thanks Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use java [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class :

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{

        String num = "80,00.34";

        NumberFormat form = NumberFormat.getInstance();

        System.out.println(form.parse(num).doubleValue());
    }

}
```

This will work for all cases except for #6 which I don't think is any valid mathematical format.

You can also get the NumberFormat instance according to your Locale by :

```
NumberFormat form = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
```

Comment: #6 "1.500.50" should be 1500.50

Answer (score 1):

Find the last index of ',' and '.' and replace all ',' and '.' up to that point with ''.

Then replace the last index of ',' or '.' with '.'

`Double.parseDouble()` the final string.

Answer (score 0):

[DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) should be useful in going to/from whatever your format is

Comment: Not that Oracle will ever go down, but any chance you could add some content to your answer to make it more SOish?