# java.lang.NumberFormatException and SystemDecimalSeparator

Tags: java

Having this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20,00"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at com.agitech.autofaces.el.FormatUtil.parseDouble(FormatUtil.java:122)
    at com.agitech.erp.converter.DoubleConverter.getAsObject(DoubleConverter.java:27)
```

after reading [decimal-separator-in-numberformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat) this, i try

```
public class FormatUtil {
    public static char ApplicationDecimalSeparator = ',';
    public static char SystemDecimalSeparator;
    static {        
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols= DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
        SystemDecimalSeparator = symbols.getDecimalSeparator();     
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(ApplicationDecimalSeparator);
    }
    public final static Double parseDouble(String d){
        if (d==null)
            return 0.0;
        return Double.parseDouble( fixDecimalSeparator(d) );
    }
    public final static String fixDecimalSeparator(String d){
        if (SystemDecimalSeparator==ApplicationDecimalSeparator)
            return d;
        return d.replaceAll( ""+SystemDecimalSeparator, ""+ApplicationDecimalSeparator);
    }
}
```

finally the SystemDecimalSeparator is already the ',' so why this exception ?

Its probably expecting 20.00 but how to get and fix this separtor ?

Indeed i test and its expectiong "20.00" instead and the default SystemDecimalSeparator is already the ','

Comment: May be worth looking at below post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the NumberFormatException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(); // Gets a NumberFormat with the default locale, you can specify a Locale as first parameter (like Locale.FRENCH)
double myNumber = f.parse("20,0").doubleValue(); // myNumber now contains 20
```

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `Double.parseDouble`, which *always* uses a dot as the decimal separator - it doesn't use the default locale at all.

[`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) is documented to behave like [`Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), which has documentation including:

> To interpret localized string representations of a floating-point value, use subclasses of `NumberFormat`.

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK: It's the documented behaviour - why would you hope I'm wrong? As I've said, if you want to parse a localized representation, use `NumberFormat`...

Comment: Given that there is another way to do its OK, thank you very mutch

Answer (score 0):

I stuck still 3 hours and basic solution is here I found.

> **Use TRY and CATCH in Data and Your crash will goes out from application.*

example:

```
try {
    Utility.setAmtOnRecept(Double.parseDouble(getAcooundNode().getNoteTotal()));                }
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```