# Detecting custom decimal separator

Tags: java, windows, locale, decimalformat

On Windows I can set a custom decimal separator character without changing my country or language settings. This is done using this little dialog:
[image]

The standard separator for my language and country is `,` and I'm changing it to `.`.

On .NET the custom separator is picket up by the system:

```
// Prints .
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);
```

In Java on the other hand it is not picked up:

```
// Prints ,
System.out.println(DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator());
```

How can I detect the custom decimal separator in Java?

**EDIT:** When I change the number format to a pre-existing one for a specific language it is picked up by Java and printed by the code in my example. It is only when I modify just the separator to a custom one that it is not picket up.

Comment: You may look this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat).

Comment: @KostasC: In my example I'm doing it in basically the same way but though the `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance()` method. It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Set the locale with the alternative constructor of `DecimalFormatSymbols`, I guess in your case german. Here [`JAVA7`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#DecimalFormatSymbols(java.util.Locale)) and [`JAVA8`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#DecimalFormatSymbols-java.util.Locale-) API's.

> Create a `DecimalFormatSymbols` object for the given locale. This constructor can only construct instances for the locales supported by the Java runtime environment, not for those supported by installed DecimalFormatSymbolsProvider implementations. For full locale coverage, use the getInstance method.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols( Locale.GERMAN );
System.out.println( dfs.getDecimalSeparator() );
```

Of course, you can get machine locale with `Locale.getDefault()`.

**UPDATE:**
 as you ask for the windows custom decimal sep... in C++ you can get it like:

```
TCHAR szSep[8];
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, szSep, 8);
```

I tried in Java with this snippet... but can't find it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

    Map<String, String> systemProperties = runtimeBean.getSystemProperties();
    Set<String> keys = systemProperties.keySet();

    System.out.println("HAY: " + systemProperties.get("LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT"));
    System.out.println("HAY: " + systemProperties.get("LOCALE_SDECIMAL"));

    for (String key : keys) {
        String value = systemProperties.get(key);
        System.out.printf("[%s] = %s.\n", key, value);
    }

}
```

Sorry... no more time today... hope that helps...

Comment: This does not answer my question. My question is about how I can detect the custom separator I have set in Windows.

Comment: "_Of course, you can get machine locale with_ `Locale.getDefault()`": This is what `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance()` is doing but it is apparently not working for custom separators.

Comment: @Lii check my update... not a definitive answer... but hope it clarifies something and you can find the way....

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Looking at the system properties as you do might give something, I'll look into that more.