# NumberFormatException for String while parsing float

Tags: java

This error is probably caused due to my different system locale. I use DOT as decimal separator.

I tried to set a default locale when my application starts but I'm getting the same exception.

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

Stacktrace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6,2" at
 sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043) at
 sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)  at
 java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
```

Comment: `i use DOT as decimal separator` .... `NumberFormatException: For input string: "6,2"`. something doesn´t sound right here.

Comment: I am pretty sure that US uses a dot too

Comment: You need to set to a Locale that uses comma instead of dot (such as German).  However, better than setting the default locale (which will have all kinds of effects applicationwide), set it on the NumberFormatter instance.

Comment: US uses dot? damn.. i was pretty sure that they used comma. Although german still gives me the same exception...

Comment: @KevinEsche my computer is set to use dot as seperator but my application always gets float inputs with comma seperators (its a website parser).

Comment: @pror21 as Thilo already said, set the decimal seperator as described [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat)

Comment: @KevinEsche Will try that again to see if it works (i just tried this before 1 hour). I will report back soon

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code is using [`Float.parseFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat-java.lang.String-). That doesn't use any locale settings. From the docs:

> Returns a new float initialized to the value represented by the specified `String`, as performed by the `valueOf` method of class Float.

And [`valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) has a detailed grammar, and includes this:

> To interpret localized string representations of a floating-point value, use subclasses of `NumberFormat`.

So basically, your default locale is irrelevant here. If you want to parse "6,2" you should be using a `NumberFormat` with a locale using comma as a decimal separator.

Comment: I'm getting: `Cannot format given Object as a Number`
This is my approach:
`NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);`
`course.setCourseGrade(Float.parseFloat(format.format(courseGrade)));`

Comment: @pror21 So you take a `float` convert it to a `String` using a `NumberFormat` then parse it back to a `float` without a locale? Does something strike you as odd here?

Comment: @pror21: You haven't explained what you're really trying to achieve. I've explained the behaviour in the question, but your comment above doesn't seem to relate to it very closely...

Comment: courseGrade is a String (contains "6,2"), i have to parse it as a float with the correct locale.

Comment: @pror21: Right, so you should be *parsing* it using a `NumberFormat`, as I said in my answer. You're currently calling `NumberFormat.format` - and then reparsing the result using `Float.parseFloat`, which won't work either... I suggest you do more research on how to use `NumberFormat` to parse strings...

Answer (score 1):

What i've finally used is this code bellow:

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
    format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

    try {
       course.setCourseGrade(format.parse(courseGrade).floatValue());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I've been at it since last night. Your code worked for me.