# How to get the environment decimal separator in Octave

Tags: octave

I need to assign to a variable the environment decimal separator in Octave.

For example, if the pc is set in US format

```
>> decsep
ans = .
```

Instead if you run the script from a pc that has European decimal format the output will be

```
>> decsep
ans = ,
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this is for _printing_ purposes only, right? I highly doubt octave makes use of this distinction in terms of code or default output. So this has little to do with octave per se, and more to do with the underlying OS; am I right in interpreting your question as "is there a way to get from within Octave the underlying OS's locale-dependent decimal-point character"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Java`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4713217/6579744) to get the decimal separator:

```
Format  = javaMethod( "getInstance", "java.text.DecimalFormat" );
Symbols = javaMethod( "getDecimalFormatSymbols", Format );
Sep     = javaMethod( "getDecimalSeparator", Symbols )
```

Alternatively you can use the following PowerShell (powershell.exe or pwsh.exe) script:

```
[~, s] = system("pwsh -command (Get-Culture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator");
Sep = s(1);
```

Comment: wonderful, it works using powershell command instead of pwsh!

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can use:

```
[~, s] =  system('locale decimal_point'); %returns decimal separator and a '↵'
decsp = s(1); %Required answer
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately I'm running Octave from Windows and I tried to run your script but it seems that 'locale decimal_point' from Windows isn't a valid argument... It's a pity, your solution was so clean! ;)

Comment: I don't think this will work because GNU Octave changes the locale for it's process (and thus `system .. locale` will always return "."). See here http://hg.octave.org/octave/file/stable/libinterp/corefcn/interpreter.cc#l414 (from the comment I guess the other software product does the same)